# I am trying to invoke a batch operation through AWS lambda. I want the batch to return the output to my lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I am invoking a batch job through AWS Lambda. The output can be seen in the cloudwatch log, however I want the output of AWS batch to be shown in the lambda logs as I intend to integrate an API with lambda. Lambda being my source of input.

Code:

```
import boto3
import json 
def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    client = boto3.client('batch') JOB_NAME = event["JobName"]
    JOB_QUEUE = "arn:aws:batch:ap-south-1:998338321653:job-queue/estimate-pi"
    JOB_DEFINITION = "arn:aws:batch:ap-south-1:998338321653:job-definition/test_batch_v2:12"
    response = client.submit_job(jobName = JOB_NAME, jobQueue = JOB_QUEUE, jobDefinition = JOB_DEFINITION, parameters = { "D": json.dumps(event)})
    print(response) 
    return (response)
```

Comment: Hi add the code or the steps you have tried.

Comment: I am using  a sample code of adding two numbers. The docker image for this is pushed into the ECR. I am giving input in lambda, and I am calling batch from there. The log on lambda is a metadata that contains the Job_Id and other information. The output is seen on the cloudwatch log, but not here.

Comment: import boto3
import json  
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('batch')
    JOB_NAME = event["JobName"]
    JOB_QUEUE = "arn:aws:batch:ap-south-1:998338321653:job-queue/estimate-pi"
    JOB_DEFINITION = "arn:aws:batch:ap-south-1:998338321653:job-definition/test_batch_v2:12"

    response = client.submit_job(
        jobName = JOB_NAME,
        jobQueue = JOB_QUEUE,
        jobDefinition = JOB_DEFINITION,
        parameters = {"D":json.dumps(event)}
        )
    
    print(response)
    return (response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible option would be using the JobId you receive when submitting the AWS Batch to call the [describeJobs API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobs.html). You can then get the logStream from the container and get the [logEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html) from your lambda function.

Comment: Hey, thank you. Can you tell me how to make that API call within my lambda function?

Comment: In the same way you are already using the boto.client for batch and then you call submit_job, you can call describe_jobs. Then using boto_client for "logs" you can call get_log_events, as seen as https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events

Comment: I am not getting the logStream name when I use describeJobsAPI. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: you should be able to see it, as long as it has already reached the RUNNING status and no more than 24 hours from the job invocation have passed. You have more information at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_states.html. If you are trying to get the LogStream before the process starts RUNNING, then you will not have the stream available. You should either keep checking the status of the job in a loop in your function, or use step functions to make sure the batch job is done before calling the next step.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Can you provide me an example as to how we can do that using step functions?

Comment: I don't have a specific example, but I believe at the step functions documentation you have one example with aws batch integration. I'm writing from my phone now so not easy to link from here, but you should be able to find it in the official docs